# Java - How many instance-methods created in memory when create multiple instances?

Tags: java

Java - I mean do instances share same **instance method** in memory?
For example:

```
public class Test {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    public Test(int a , int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    /* instance method - sum() */
    public int sum(){
        return a+b;
    }

    public static void man(String[] args) {     
        Test t1 = new Test(3,4);
        Test t2 = new Test(5,6);

        t1.sum();
        t2.sum();           
    }
}
```

I know when apply `new` keyword to a class, class variables (properties) will be copied. So instances can have their own property values separately.

But how about method? will it also make a copy? If so, just waste memory resources, because the methods are always same.

what happended in JVM when using a `new` keyword ? thanks very much!

> NOTE: official doc reference is highly preferred :)

Comment: All instances share the same code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But how about method? will it also make a copy? If so, just waste
>   memory resources, because the methods are always same.

No, there will always be a single copy of each method (in the *method area* of the JVM). This applies for both `static` and `non-static` methods.

> Are there some kindly people tell me what happended in JVM when using
>   a new keyword ? thanks very much!

Simply put, a `new` Object is created in the heap space by calling the appropriate constructor. A reference to that object is returned.

Comment: Strictly speaking you may have several JIT-compiled versions of the same method concurrently residing in memory. For example, less-optimized version which is running right now, so cannot be removed and newly-compiled more-optimized version which will be used when the same method is called next time. But of course these versions are not bound to the specific object instances.

Comment: Single copy each method memory on app startup? If no use method still single copy created in memory?

Answer (score 1):

Methods of a class is stored on stack in .class instance which stores all methods of a class. Only one copy is created for method and it is invoked by all instance of the class.JVM keeps reference of all methods defined in a class and linked it with instance when it calls a  method.

> what happended in JVM when using a new keyword ?

When we simply put 'new' keyword it creates an object on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

All instances share the same code.

If you compile your Java class and create an instance inside of another class of it, they will call the function on the same Java class (.class)-File.

Answer (score 0):

Of course virtual calls make things somewhat more complex, but basically instance method is like a static method with additional implicit `this` parameter. Calling `t1.sum()` is like calling `sum(t1)` (with additional null check for `t1`). No reason to duplicate the method for every possible parameter value.